# NOT IN Dax equivalent

Tags: powerbi, dax

still very new to DAX and hate it so far. where is the logic?

I have an expression below that creates data for a column based on if the data meets the criteria. What I have is a WORKING example of the opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish. I really, really want to be able to type "NOT IN" but it seems like that is not an option in DAX syntax. So basically, how do I EXCLUDE these values?

```
Column = 


    IF ( MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_Center] IN {"FillRate","CancelRt","NoShowRt","ExamRt"}, MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[NewUnits] )
```

Would love for THIS to work:

```
Column = 


    IF ( MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_Center] NOT IN {"FillRate","CancelRt","NoShowRt","ExamRt"}, MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[NewUnits] )
```

Comment: In DAX we have NOT operator
https://dax.guide/not/

IF ( NOT ( MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_Center] IN {"FillRate","CancelRt","NoShowRt","ExamRt"} ), MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[NewUnits] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF ( NOT ( MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[Revenue_Center] IN {"FillRate","CancelRt","NoShowRt","ExamRt"} ), MMP_Dashboards_WMH_PBI[NewUnits] )
```